# Animating arbitrary layer property in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I'm trying to do something in iOS that I've successfully done on Mac OS X.  It is not working and it is not clear to me if this is just not supported in iOS, or if I have something wrong.

I am trying to animate an arbitrary property of my CALayer.  I have a subclass of CAEAGLLayer defined like this:

```
@interface ChartViewLayer : CAEAGLLayer
{
    ChartView       *chartView;
    float           chartXOffset;
    float           chartYOffset;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) ChartView *chartView;
@property (nonatomic, assign) float     chartXOffset;
@property (nonatomic, assign) float     chartYOffset;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber  *chartXOffsetNumber;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber  *chartYOffsetNumber;


@end
```

The implementation of ChartViewLayer does create the appropriate getters and setters, which work.

I also define the following in ChartViewLayer:

```
+ (BOOL)needsDisplayForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    if ( [key isEqualToString:@"chartXOffsetNumber"] || [key isEqualToString:@"chartYOffsetNumber"] )
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return [super needsDisplayForKey:key];
    }
}
```

The above is because I need to redisplay the chartViewLayer when the animated property changes.

To do the actual animation, I do the following:

```
//Animate the chartViewLayer offset
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
CABasicAnimation *offsetAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"chartYOffsetNumber"];
[offsetAnim setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:startOffset]];
[offsetAnim setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:endOffset]];
[chartViewLayer addAnimation:offsetAnim forKey:@"animateOffset"];
```

What I see is the animation apparently trying to proceed.  My layer's display method is called for each frame of the animation.  I verify that with NSLog().  However, the actual setter to modify the property does not seem to be getting called.

```
- (void)setChartYOffsetNumber:(NSNumber *)value
{
    chartYOffset = [value floatValue];
    NSLog(@"Setting y offset number to %f", chartYOffset);
}
```

So although the display method is called as if I need to redisplay when the property changes, the actual property is not getting changed.

Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong?  Or is this not supposed to work on iOS like it does on Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Animation makes copies of your layers. If you have custom properties, they won't be transferred over. The canonical way to do manage this is to implement `initWithLayer:` like this:

```
- (id)initWithLayer:(CALayer *)other {
    self = [super initWithLayer:other];
    if (self) {
      self.chartView = other.chartView;
      self.charXOffset = other.chartXOffset;
      ...
    }
    return self;
}
```

In my experience, however, you can do just as well by declaring all of your properties as `@dynamic`, and it'll just automatically work. I spoke with some of the developers during WWDC, and it's unclear whether this is actually expected behavior.

I don't remember this being any different in Mac. Are you sure this is exactly the same code?

You may find the [Animating Custom Layers](http://cocoaheads.tv/animating-custom-layer-properties-by-rob-napier/) talk useful.

Comment: Rob, yes I was aware of that and I have basically that identical code in my layer subclass.  For whatever reason it was not solving the problem.  However I was able to fix it by digging the offset out of the presentation layer rather than the model layer when my display method was getting called.  That make it work.  May someday I'll investigate why the initWithLayer wasn't solving this for me.